# How to reduce bitmap quality without affecting it's size?

Tags: android, bitmap

How to reduce bitmap quality without affecting it's size?

this is my recursive function to get :

```
private String compressIv1(Bitmap b , int quality){

        long size_on_disk = 0;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, byteArrayOutputStream1);
        byte[] byteArray1 = byteArrayOutputStream1 .toByteArray();
        App.registerBitmapModel.bitmapSize1  = byteArray1.length/1024;

        size_on_disk = byteArray1.length/1024;
        Log.e("size_on_disk","=>"+size_on_disk);
        Bitmap temp_b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray1, 0, byteArray1.length);

        if(quality <= 0)
            return "";

        if(size_on_disk >= 1000)
        {
            quality = quality - 10;
            compressIv1(temp_b,quality);
        }else{
            encodedImg1 = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Base64.encodeToString(byteArray1, Base64.DEFAULT);

            return encodedImg1;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

but I get the same size:

```
  Log.e("size_on_disk","=>"+size_on_disk);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `PNG` format is lossless, it will ignore the quality setting, so the result of your compress is always the same. Here is the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream)):

> quality - int: Hint to the compressor, 0-100. 0 meaning compress for small size, 100 meaning compress for max quality. Some formats, like PNG which is lossless, will ignore the quality setting